# Transferring data between two Access databases

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am writing a simple reporting tool that will need to move data from a table in one Access database to a table in another Access database (the table structure is identical).  However, I am new to C# and am finding it hard to come up with a reliable solution.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stupid question but are the tables actually access tables? A lot of people use Access as a frontend with another DB provider (SQL, MySQL etc) to store the actual data, the answer to your question would be different which is why I ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access SQL supports using an IN clause to specify that a table resides in a different database. The following C# code SELECTs rows from a table named [YourTable] in `Database1.accdb` and INSERTs them into an existing table named [YourTable] (with the identical structure) in `Database2.accdb`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace oleDbTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myConnectionString;
            myConnectionString =
                    @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                    @"Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;";

            using (var con = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                con.Open();

                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText =
                        @"INSERT INTO YourTable IN 'C:\Users\Public\Database2.accdb' " +
                        @"SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ID < 103";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious: Why do some people choose to code in a ....*wordy* fashion? I mean, the `OleDbConnection` has an overload that accepts the database connection string, and the `OleDbCommand` has an overload that accepts the SQL text and the `OleDbConnection`. Is there a benefit? I've got dual monitors, tiny fonts, and split screens in my developing environment; yet, I still can't get all the code I want to see at one time on the screen.

Comment: @jp2code In my opinion, the main benefit in writing *sample code* this way is that it is explicit. People who are just starting out using a given language or tool don't have to be familiar with a particular overload and they don't have to deduce (or guess at) what is being initialized when the object is instantiated. In my case I also have a generic C# console app that I use for testing ("oleDbTest"), and I sometimes have several different variable assignments (e.g., `myConnectionString`) that I copy and paste to suit; I then delete all the extra ones when posting code here.

Comment: Storing such strings in variables also makes it convenient to inspect them for debugging purposes.  Debugging ease trumps concise.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways.

0) If it's only once, copy and paste the table.

1) If you want to do this inside Access, the easiest way is to create a linked table in the new database, and then a make table query in the new database.

2) You can reference the second table directly.
SELECT *
FROM TableInDbX IN 'C:\SomeFolder\DB X';

3) In a macro, you can use the TransferDatabase method of the DoCmd object to link relevant tables and then run suitable append and update queries to synchronize.

4) VBA
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/questions/new_mdb.php

Answer (score 0):

Given column names `Col1`, `Col2`, and `Col3`:

```
private static void Migrate(string dbConn1, string dbConn2) {
  // DataTable to store your info into
  var table = new DataTable();
  // Modify your SELECT command as needed
  string sqlSelect = "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM aTableInOneAccessDatabase ";
  // Notice this uses the connection string to DB1
  using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlSelect, new OleDbConnection(dbConn1))) {
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    cmd.Connection.Close();
  }
  // Modify your INSERT command as needed
  string sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO aTableInAnotherAccessDatabase " +
    "(Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (@Col1, @Col2, @Col3) ";
  // Notice this uses the connection string to DB2
  using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlInsert, new OleDbConnection(dbConn2))) {
    // Modify these database parameters to match the signatures in the new table
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Col1", DbType.Int32);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Col2", DbType.String, 50);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Col3", DbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
      // Fill in each parameter with data from your table's row
      cmd.Parameters["@Col1"].Value = row["Col1"];
      cmd.Parameters["@Col2"].Value = row["Col2"];
      cmd.Parameters["@Col3"].Value = row["Col3"];
      // Insert that data
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    cmd.Connection.Close();
  }
}
```

Now, I do not work with Access databases very often, so you may need to tweak something up there.

That should get you well on your way, though.

### Worth noting:

If I remember correctly, Access does NOT pay attention to your OleDbParameter names! You could call them whatever you want, and in fact most people just use a question mark `?` for the parameter fields.

So, you have to add and update these parameters in the same order that your statement calls them.

So, why did I name the parameters `@Col1`, `@Col2`, `@Col3`? Here, it just to help you and me understand where each parameter is intended to map to. It is also good practice to get into. If you ever migrate to a better database, hopefully it will pay attention to what the parameters are named.

Comment: Thank you everyone for you excellent help - it really is very much appreciated (and interesting).  All the best.